# The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, controller, annotation

Não estou conseguindo importar a annotation `@CrossOrigin`. A ide não encontra o pacote necessário apesar de todas as outras *annotations* estarem funcionando normalmente. O erro que ocorre é esse:

> The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin cannot be resolved

Está faltando alguma dependência no meu maven?

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A anotação @CrossOrigin foi adicionada ao Spring na versão 4.2 e você está usando a versão `4.0.6.RELEASE`. Mude sua versão para a mais recente do Spring `4.3.6.RELEASE` e Isso resolverá o problema.

Além disso, como você está usando o Spring Boot, as seguintes dependências não precisam ser declaradas no seu `pom.xml` já que elas são dependências do próprio Spring Boot:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```